# Saving list changes to local storage in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-typescript

I have a collection of lists of called `allLists`, when I make changes like adding a new list or updating a existing list in `allLists` I want the changes to be saved to local storage. I'm having trouble with this, when I refresh it does not seem to work.

**Custom localstorage hook:**

```
export function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue, mapper = (str) => str) {
  const getInitialValue = () =>
    localStorage.getItem(key) !== null
      ? mapper(localStorage.getItem(key))
      : defaultValue;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(getInitialValue);
  const setAndStoreValue = (newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== "") {
      setValue(newValue);
      localStorage.setItem(key, newValue);
    }
  };
  return [value, setAndStoreValue];
}
```

**How I'm using saving to allList to localstorage**

```
const [allLists, setAllLists] = useLocalStorage('allLists', [initialLists]);
```

**Codesandbox example:**
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-saving-changes-to-localstorage-4otnq?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving and fetching values from `localStorage` is not working due to lack of a valid `serializer` and `deserializer`. You can update your `useLocalStorage` hook to have an implementation with a default `serializer` (`JSON.stringify`) and `deserializer` (`JSON.parse`) as below :-

```
export function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue, {serializer = JSON.stringify,deserializer=JSON.parse}={}) {
  const getInitialValue = () =>
    localStorage.getItem(key) !== null
      ? deserializer(localStorage.getItem(key))
      : defaultValue;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(getInitialValue);
  const setAndStoreValue = (newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== "") {
      setValue(newValue);
      localStorage.setItem(key, serializer(newValue));
    }
  };
  return [value, setAndStoreValue];
}
```

Forked Codesandbox :-

[image: Edit React - saving changes to localstorage (forked)]

**Note :-** You might need additional logic to handle cases where you try to **deserialize** using `JSON.parse(..)` a string instead of a stringified object since that will result in error. You can pass a custom function to your hook that handles all this for you.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to save now but I'm getting `A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.` you get recreate this by refreshing the codesandbox after creating new list and adding elements

Comment: Can you try `localStorage.clear()` in the browser console or your codesandbox’s console and try adding new items and refreshing page again ? The forked sandbox seems to work for me.

Comment: I tried that, still same error. did you try adding multiple elements then right clicking the browser and reload?

Comment: I have updated the forked sandbox. Can you try again ? The problem is with how you are using `setAllLists`. It won't work like **stateSetter** which gets returned from `useState` because it's a custom function for which you have not handled this scenario i.e. passing in a function as a parameter.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I dont see any changes in setAllLists, did you save it?

Comment: Seems like it works now, I cleared the localStorage again

Comment: Is there a way to see the diff between mine and your codesandbox?

Comment: I am not aware about that. Some googling might help !